# HTML <a> link that doenst' set referere?

Tags: html, browser, header

is there a way to make a link to a page and tell to the browser to don't set the referer on the new request?

I tried `target="_blank"` but chrome always put the referer header.

Thanks

Comment: could you be more clear as to what you mean by the referer header?

Comment: @Daniel: He means the `HTTP_REFERER` header that the browser sends to the requested URL when following a web link. Interesting question.

Comment: Can you use JavaScript? Can you use server side scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add the attribute `rel="noreferrer` to the anchor element:

```
<a href="www.example.com" rel="noreferrer">noreferrer!</a>
```

This is a new feature introduced in HTML5, so it is not supported in all browsers.

EDIT: [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29#Other_features), only Webkit supports it currently. More generally, you may not prevent a Referer header to be sent altogether, because the client does what it wants in the end...

Comment: To be exact, in this case "not supported in all browsers" actually means "not supported anywhere". This is useless today.

Comment: Maybe in recent versions of Webkit-based browsers? Anyway, I want to stress that it's not to be relied upon, because you can't control what the client does, what the client supports. There is __no way__ to prevent the client from sending what it wants.

Comment: Sure! Anyway it's being standardized within HTML5, so I expect support in other browsers to be coming in a few months/years.

Answer (score 1):

You can hijack the anchor's click event using javascript and send a custom HTTP header. Then replace the body with the new page. But keep in mind, that this is generally not a good implementation, and should only be used if you really need this and are running out of choices. For one, this won't generate a history for the browser.

Here's a quick sample code for JQuery. I haven't tested it, but it should give you a basic idea.

```
$( "#myLink" ).click( function()
{
    $.ajax({
       beforeSend: function(req) 
       {
          req.setRequestHeader("Referer", "");
       },
       type:"GET",
       url: "[proper url]",
       success: function( result )
       {
          $("body").html( result );
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: and how would you do that (not the hijack but sending the custom http header?)

Comment: @rene: See the line `setRequestHeader`.

Comment: Hm i don't know if i can use this because the link it's not to a "page" but it's a link to a file

Comment: I think it's a good practical solution, but again, be aware that it's not 100%-guaranteed.